# NestJS TypeORMCrudService

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I need to use one of the basic TypeORMCrudService methods, for example, createOne, I got the body as dto(I guess) but the second parameter is the CrudRequest. Should I redefine its methods or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand what you mean:
if you use repositoryT it's so easy to do it:

your controller should be like this:

```
@Get(':id')
  async findOne(@Param('id', ParseIdPipe) id: number) {
    return await this.unitService.findOne(id);
  }
```

your service should be like this:

```
  async findOne(id: number, ...relations: string[]): Promise<Entity> {
    const record = await this.repository.findOne(id, { relations });
    this.checkNotFound(record);
    return record;
  }
```

you can use :

```
const record = await this.repository.findOne(id, { relations });
const record = await this.repository.create({dto});
const record = await this.repository.find();
const record = await this.repository.delete(id);
const record = await this.repository.update(id, {dto});
```

Comment: thank you so much, but instead I could've just use the controller property "repo" that has all the basic methods to work with.